# Ubuntu 14.04 GNU Radio Error

Tags: cmake, ubuntu-14.04, gnuradio

I'm new to using GNU Radio and was trying to build my own out-of-tree module following the instruction [here](http://gnuradio.org/redmine/projects/gnuradio/wiki/OutOfTreeModules). But I get the following error when I run `cmake ../` inside the build directory:

```
checking for module 'gnuradio-runtime'
--   package 'gnuradio-runtime' not found
-- Could NOT find GNURADIO_RUNTIME (missing:  GNURADIO_RUNTIME_LIBRARIES)
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:98 (message):
GnuRadio Runtime required to compile mypack


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

I would be a great help if anyone can help me fix this. I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 (Trusty Tahr).

Answer (score 1):

This error indicates your OOT was built against GNU Radio 3.7.0 or higher and you are using an old GNU Radio version to build it (e.g. 3.6.X).